# How to show active filters as columns on ActiveAdmin index pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin with Ruby on Rails to develop an admin section of a webapp. I'm building an index page for a model that has a lot of attributes. Most of these attributes I've enabled filters for, but I can't show them all on the index table because it becomes too cluttered. Is there a way to dynamically show/hide columns on the table based on what filters are used? Is there a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a bit of an answer to this problem, but it's not pretty and definitely not very DRY.

You can actually use `if` statements inside the ActiveAdmin DSL `index` method. Also, ActiveAdmin passes filters as a `q[]` GET parameter. For instance, a string field named "username" would be the `q[username_contains]` GET parameter. A numeric field named "number_of_posts" could be `q[number_of_posts_eq]`. Using this we can look at an example where we display number of posts if they've been filtered, or the user's email address, if they haven't:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
    index do
        column :username
        column :first_name
        column :last_name
        if(params[:'q[number_of_posts_eq]'])
            column :number_of_posts
        else
            column :email
        end
    end

    filter :number_of_posts
end
```

Of course, there are many different filter types, so the query parameters are all going to be different depending on the type. Even the numeric type has `_eq`, `_lt`, and `_gt` suffixes for equals, less-than, and greater-than respectively.